# Horizontal barplot in seaborn with numeric independent data

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

This is the [Seaborn Doc on how to make a horizontal boxplot.](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/horizontal_barplot.html)  You'll notice that they use some dataset called crashes and are graphing some categorical variable vs some numeric variable.  To make it horizontal, they are just flipping the x and y variable, easy enough.

My issue is that my categories are numeric which causes problems.  A minimum reproducible example uses their dataset.  Basically this should be the same graph one horizontal and the other vertical.  As you can see they are both vertical...

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")


crashes = sns.load_dataset("car_crashes").sort_values("total", ascending=False)

crashes['roundTotal'] = np.round(crashes['total']).astype(int)
crashesMod = crashes.groupby(['roundTotal']).count().reset_index()
crashesMod['VsAverage'] = crashesMod['total'] > crashesMod.total.mean()

sns.barplot(x = 'roundTotal', y = 'total', hue = 'VsAverage', data = crashesMod)
plt.show()
sns.barplot(y = 'roundTotal', x = 'total', hue = 'VsAverage', data = crashesMod)
```

[image]

I tried making the column 'roundTotal' of type string as I imagined that it was doing some guessing under the hood and was failing with the 2 numeric types, but then I run into
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: Use pandas to make it a categorical variable: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html

Comment: or `orient="h"`

Comment: you also likely want `dodge=False` here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this before plotting:

```
crashesMod.roundTotal=crashesMod.roundTotal.astype('category')
crashesMod.VsAverage=crashesMod.VsAverage.astype('category')
```

Comment: better to use the `assign` method of the dataframe rather than rely on the dot-accessors of the columns

Comment: @qwertylpc use `.assign` to create an entirely new column for plotting. You could even pipe that result directly to seaborn so that it's entirely ephemeral.

Comment: @PaulH Do you know how to control the ordering of the columns.  For example the y axis is going from 6-24 (in the example) descending instead of ascending.  I just tried calling `sort_values()`

Comment: @qwertylpc see my answer below

Answer (score 4):

According the the seaborn docs, you should use the 'orient' option:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3.5, 6))

crashes = (
    sns.load_dataset("car_crashes")
        .sort_values("total", ascending=False)
        .assign(roundTotal=lambda df: df['total'].round().astype(int).astype('category'))
        .groupby(['roundTotal']).count()
        .reset_index()
        .assign(VsAverage=lambda df: df['total'] > df['total'].mean())
        .pipe((sns.barplot, 'data'), y='roundTotal', x='total',
              hue='VsAverage', orient='horizonal', ax=ax)
)

ax.invert_yaxis()
```

And that gives me:

[image]